# Can I use CalDAV with Outlook for free?

Tags: outlook, caldav

Can I use CalDAV with Outlook without buying additional software?
I found many resources where says, that if you want use CalDAV with Outlook, you need pay. Is it really so?

Comment: Not a programming question. No research done. https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0):

Outlook does not support CalDAV out of the box, you need a plugin / extra software.

There are commercial offerings for such as well as open source offerings (e.g. you can find https://github.com/aluxnimm/outlookcaldavsynchronizer using a simple search in your favourite search engine).

However, this isn't a programming question and doesn't belong here.